# Create Tree like strucure in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, tree

I need to represent my data like a Tree structure in UI.How can I create a view like this in iPhone? Is there any default items for this in `object library`  ? If no how can I manually implement this?

[image]

Comment: How huge this tree can be? Is it interactive?

Comment: maximum 64 Nodes..yes the nodes are interactive(probably buttons)

Comment: For 64 nodes there also should be scrolling/zooming

Comment: yes. I know. I have used pinch zoom before.So that part is not a problem.

Comment: @Harikrishnan did you see my response? it seems that a lot of work has been done here

Comment: @Alban Yes.I'm checking it.Almost what I need.But that has no provision for adding nodes to tree.

Comment: Yes, but there is enough elements to add this feature, you can check my edit :)

Comment: Did you draw this? How useful is the PSTreeGraph? Do you know any other lib in Swift?

Comment: Yes. I have used this for my project. It is useful. I don't know about Swift libs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project on github called PSTreeGraph made by Ed Preston

https://github.com/epreston/PSTreeGraph

Author says that it is for iPad but work also on iPhone, 
simply by changing the device to iPhone in xcode "deployment info"

In addition, it's interactive.

EDIT

Possibility to add node "manually":

In `PSHTreeGraphViewController.m`

you have an entry point `[self setRootClassName:@"UIControl"];`

here you can check how to create the tree.

That project also gives you data model : `ObjCClassWrapper`

And finally there is a method (delegate)

```
-(void) configureNodeView:(UIView *)nodeView
            withModelNode:(id <PSTreeGraphModelNode> )modelNode
```

called on a node tap.

Everything to create a custom interactive tree!

Comment: It's working in class level. ie sub-class super class concept...How can I represent dynamic data with this?

Comment: Your question is about a Tree structure in UI, this project display a tree structure, you just have to change the model, everything is well documented and structured... Take a look at PSTreeGraphModelNode: The example displays a part of iOS SDK classes, but you can change this values

Answer (score 4):

There is in Core Foundation something like [CFTree](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/Articles/usingtrees.html)

But, to be honest, I wouldn't use it, because it is too low level and it's in pure C. It would be better to implement tree structure by your own.

You can achieve it in many different ways, depending on what kind of tree you want to have.
Here is an example of the easiest interface:

```
@interface XYNode : NSObject
  @property(nonatomic, readonly) YourDataObjectType *data;
  @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSSet *children;
  @property(nonatomic, readonly) XYNode *parent;

  + (instancetype)nodeWithParent:(XYNode *)parent data:(YourDataObjectType *)data;
  - (instancetype)initWithParent:(XYNode *)parent data:(YourDataObjectType *)data;

  - (void)addChildNode:(id)node;
  - (void)removeChildNode:(id)node;
@end
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I don't think it's the structure the OP is having trouble with, it's the view.